# Unit testing javascript promises

Tags: javascript, promise

My code fetches data from a server via ajax and uses promises.

How do I write a unit text for this code?

```
function getPromise(){ 
  var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
    http.get({ 
      host: 'localhost', 
      port: 3000, 
      path: '/blist'
    }, function(res) { 
      if(res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode>300) { 
        reject('statusCode=' + res.statusCode); 
        return; 
      } 
      var data=""; 
      res.on('data', function (chunk) { 
        data += chunk; 
        resolve(data); 
        return; 
      }); 
      res.on('error', function(error) { 
        console.log("Got error: " + e.message); 
        reject(error); 
      }); 
    }) 
  }); 
  return p; 
}
```

Comment: Can you add a more condensed example?

Comment: Show us what have you tried till now?

Comment: i create this func to call getPromise()
module.exports = {
   list: function(req,res){
    var p = getPromise();
    p.then(function(data){
        res.send(data);
       }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
       })
   }
  }

Comment: @flower, in your unit test, you can mock the $http service. Take a look at this doc. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the server response with [nock](https://github.com/node-nock/nock) and assert the promise value via [mocha](https://mochajs.org)

```
describe('promise' function (done) {
  getPromise.then(response => {
    // assert response
    done()
  })
}
```

Comment: can u explain more what do u mean?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'd want to test the promise function, whether it's gonna do what's expected if you fake an http call.

For that you might wanna consider passing in http object and the callback it takes as parameters so you can mock them and simulate the success and error responses in your tests.

Something like

```
getPromise(http, req, callback) {
  var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) -> {
    http.get(req, callback);
    callback.on('data', data -> { // Resolve or reject looking at the status code })
  })
  return promise;
}
```

Then you can mock your callback as well as http#get function to test your scenarios